# How to use virtual class in c++ to call method from other class?

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, instance, virtual

I am trying to call a method from one class in  another class using virtual classes. I tried several ways of instantiating the virtual class but always get some errors, what am I doing wrong? These are the three code pieces.

I am trying to use a virtual class SimData.h:

```
#ifndef SIMDATA_H_
#define SIMDATA_H_

class SimData
{
public:
virtual void onSimUpdate(int id)=0;
};

#endif /* SIMDATA_H_ */
```

To call a function from maintask.h

```
...
class maintask : public SimData
{
public:
     virtual void onSimUpdate(int id);
...
```

In another class Select.cpp

```
.....
SimData* dat;

dat->onSimUpdate(value1); --->HERE IS THE ERROR THAT IT IS NOT INITIALIZED
.....
```

Do you know how I call the abstract class correctly in the Select.cpp file?

Thank you.

Comment: SimData* dat = new maintask(); ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a pointer to `SimData`. You need to make it point to an instance. For example,

```
SimData* dat;
maintask m;
dat = &m; // dat now points to m
dat->onSimUpdate(value1); // OK now
```

Note that calling `new maintask()` would yield a pointer to a `maintask` that you can assign to `dat`. I haven't used that example because dynamic allocation and polymorphism via pointers are two separate issues. Furthermore, dealing with raw `new`ed pointers is fraught with peril.

Here is a more realistic example, still without dynamic allocation, and even without pointers:

```
void foo(SimData& data, int x) { dat.onSimUpdate(x); }

maintask m;
foo(m, 42);
```

Comment: I think you mean `data.onSimUpdate(x);`. :)

Comment: @rightfold Yikes! I got confused with all the pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
SimData* dat;
dat->onSimUpdate(value1);
```

In the code above, it has nothing to do with the virtual function, and everything to do with the fact that you never initialized the pointer (it is pointing to never-never land).  You must assign it to something:

```
SimData* dat = new maintask;
dat->onSimUpdate(value1); // this will now work
// NOTE:  you need to delete dat at some point!
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of raw pointers, use a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<SimData> dat(new maintask());
dat->onSimUpdate(value1);
// deletion will happen automatically; no need to do it yourself
```

Prefer `std::make_unique` if available (if not, look it up).

Raw pointers, unlike smart pointers, have three major issues:

- They require manual memory management, leading to unmaintainable and unreadable code.
- They make code exceptionally exception-unsafe because an exception may occur between `new` and `delete` calls.
- They lead to unclear semantics: which pointers ought to be used with `delete` and which oughtn’t?